# Is it okay to submit one by one request on my database? or submit whole by array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, transactions

I am creating a questionnaire web application,

I wonder if it is better to submit every answer of the user one by one on my database (It means more request) or I'm just gonna store each answer on an array and when the question already done, that's the time I'm gonna submit it as a whole, so that there will be only one request.

What are the software complexity, performance and ACID implications of

- doing a sequence of INSERT operations, one for each question, vs.
- doing just one multi-row INSERT?

Does this make any difference or not?

Comment: With respect, the answer to this question is *not* a matter of opinion. It's a matter of performance and atomicity. And, from a new SQLer, it's a good question. Please consider reopening it.

Comment: Hi Sir, I am not really asking for a opinion, but I am asking what is the best method to do this? I think my question can be a big help to the beginners like me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** Use a transaction.

I guess you want to know whether this ...

```
INSERT INTO answers (person_id, quiz_id, question_id, answer)
       VALUES (111,222,1,"yes");
INSERT INTO answers (person_id, quiz_id, question_id, answer)
       VALUES (111,222,2,"no");
```

is better or worse than this ...

```
INSERT INTO answers (person_id, quiz_id, question_id, answer)
       VALUES (111,222,1,"yes"),
              (111,222,2,"no");
```

I suggest the second option. Why?

- It's a so-called [*atomic operation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)) carried out in an [*implicit transaction*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html). That is, it all happens at once, and if it fails for some reason it all fails. (This *atomic* has the sense of "indivisible", not the sense of "nuclear power".)
- It's slightly less work for the MySQL server, because transactions take work; your first option has (in my example) two implicit transactions and the second has only one.

But, it has to be said, programming the second option is more work for you, especially if you parameterize your INSERT query ([mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)) to avoid [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  You should avoid it. Because cybercreeps.

There's a good middle path here that will get you the programming simplicity benefits of your first choice and the atomicity and performance benefits of your second.

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO answers (person_id, quiz_id, question_id, answer)
       VALUES (111,222,1,"yes");
INSERT INTO answers (person_id, quiz_id, question_id, answer)
       VALUES (111,222,2,"no");
COMMIT;
```

Comment: so i should go on my second option right? that's what i am doing right now, and i realized that, more request is more cost. thats why i am trying to maximize the request that i am doing.

Comment: No, my suggestion is, for programming and testing simplicity, to use your *first* option. But wrap your INSERT operations in START TRANSACTION;  / COMMIT;  . Doing this will make your first option perform as well as your second option. In practice the COMMIT is the big work for the MySQL server, Without START TRANSACTION your first option has multiple implicit commits, so burdens the MySQL server slightly more.

Answer (score 0):

To me it depends on the size of the request at the end and the user behavior.
Considering the first option, if he leaves before the end at least you have stored the first questions. You can do it if it has any value for your analysis.
If you send one request at the end, for me it's also a solution, then just be careful about the size of it. But you loose the informations if the user leaves before.